# UITableView in iPhone app - how to get number of rows

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

How can i store the number of current rows in a uitable into a variable?

This is my code for the table (that i think might be relevant):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question. That method looks fine, why do you want to change it? If you want to store it, why not simply store it in an ivar?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it either?! Isn't it just the case of storing [sectionInfo numberOfObjects] into an NSInteger on the method above?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should really get this from the source of the data, rather than the table view itself, I'd have thought. (It's a bit arse about face as they'd say around here.)

That said, you could use the `numberOfRowsInSection:` method within the UITableView as you've shown in your example.

Comment: How do i store the value in a variable using this method though?

Comment: Er... it is stored in the data source (e.g.: NSArray as the count method, etc.) You could of course duplicate this using an instance variable if that's what you mean, but I'm not sure of the value of doing this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to display a uiAlert if the number of rows goes above 1. But i dont know how to

Answer (score 2):

Typically you'll have a data source that's backing the UITableView, usually array. In that case you could simply do [myDataSourceArr count].

Comment: Its backed by core data as its data source

Comment: In that case you will have a NSFetchedResultsController, and you can use [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]

Answer (score 0):

*I want to display a uiAlert if the number of rows goes above 1. But i dont know how to*

That's easy, just check if your value in this case is above 0:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo =
      [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
  if([sectionInfor numberOfObjects]>0){
      <<Put your code here>>
  }
      return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]];
}
```